# Omitting only the page number of chapter's heading in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How can I remove the page number of the chapter's header in ToC, without removing the page numbers of the preface pages?

For example, in my Table of Contents, I have,

```
Acknowledgments               ii
table of contents            iii
...
abstract                    viii

Chapter
1 Chapter one                 1
  1.1 Section one             1
...
2 Chapter two                 2 
2.1 Section one               2 
... and so on...
```

How to remove the first page number 1 or 2 that related to the chapters' headers without touching the page numbers of the preface pages?

As for the document class, I am using `\documentclass[doublelespace,tocchapterhead]`, together with file `.cls` of what I think was originally called `chicagothesis` or something like that.

I have tried to to removed `#2` in:

```
\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
```

But the result was, the page numbers of all headers have been removed. Is there any way to control that? I do not want to use `tocloft` package or `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to the `.cls` file you speak of?

Comment: Hello Werner, How can I provide it? Is there anyway? As far as I know, there is no link online for the .cls file that I am using. I only have it as a file.

Comment: You mention "`chicagothesis` or something" which isn't very specific. A quick search on Google provided [`easychithesis.cls`](http://www.gae.ucm.es/~abelardo/tesis/styles/chicago/easychithesis.cls) which shows the same code snippet for `\l@chapter` you provide. Is this it? If all else fails, paste the code for the `.cls` on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and provide a link to it in your original post via an edit.

Comment: Hello again Werner, here is the link you asked me for: http://pastebin.com/nNBrUASu. I have just logged in, I will look into the answer below, I hope it will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following *should* work for most document classes, although without the actual document class it is difficult to test.

You can selectively turn on the use of page numbers in the ToC using the following macros: `\gobbletocpage` and `\restoretocpage`. The former redefines `\addtocontents`, replacing `\thepage` with `\relax` (effectively doing nothing), while the latter restores this back to `\thepage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\gobbletocpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\relax}}}
}%
\newcommand{\restoretocpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\thepage}}}
}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\gobbletocpage
\section{A section}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\restoretocpage
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

By means of example, the above ToC is void of page numbers after a call to `\gobbletocpage` (Section 1.3 and Chapter 2), and this is restored with `\restoretocpage`.

---

Since you have access to the `.cls`, replace your definition of `\l@chapter` (and some surrounding code) with the following (lines 182-219):

```
% Change style of printing chapters in ToC to match chapter headings.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Always number up to \subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Include up to \subsection in ToC
\newcommand{\thechappagenum}{}% Empty page number for chapter
\newif\ifchappagenum\chappagenumtrue

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\thechappagenum}{\ifchappagenum#2\fi}% Include chapter page num based on \chappagenum boolean
  \typeout{\thechappagenum}
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip .1cm \@plus \p@ %{the v-distance between the headings in the contents}
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}% %{the distance between the number of the chapter and its title}
    \begingroup
           \parindent\z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance \leftskip \@tempdima 
      \hskip  -\leftskip 
      \etchapterheadstyle{#1}\nobreak
% : The following 3 lines add dots to the chapter TOC listings
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
      \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \thechappagenum}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
%---------------------------------------------------  
% The lines below responsible on the mechanism of removing pages numbers of selecting headers in ToC.
% We need to add the command \gobbletocpage in the preamble before the \include{chapter} to delete their page numbers in ToC. And,
% we need to add the command \restoretocpage to restore chapter page numbering in ToC
%---------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\gobbletocpage}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chappagenumfalse}}%
\newcommand{\restoretocpage}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chappagenumtrue}}%
%---------------------------------------------------
```

The above defines a new boolean "condition" `\ifchappagenum` that is set to `false` (`\chappagenumfalse`) by `\gobbletocpage` and `true` (`\chappagenumtrue`) by `\restoretocpage`.  All of this is written to the `.toc` file, since this is processed without any knowledge/before the rest of your document.

Use `\gobbletocpage` *before* the chapter(s) that you want no page numbers for in the ToC, and `\restoretocpage` *before* you want to restore the chapter page numbers. This condition can be modified and used to reformat chapter ToC entries as needed (not just page numbers). Here's your [`easythesis.cls`](http://pastebin.com/V1r87cP8) with the above modifications used in a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{easythesis}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\gobbletocpage
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Werner, I have applied the example on my cls and tex files. It worked.  I am grateful.
The thing is, the design of the preamble of the thesis depends on \include, and therefore, the chapters are independent files. Thus, when I added the redefinition commands to the cls file, and added \gobbletocpage before each \include{chapter}, the result was deleting the page numbers of the sections, subsections as well. So, I had to add \restoretocpage inside each chapter before the first section of each one. Is there a way to make it automatically all in cls file?

Comment: UPDATE: Hello Werner. The link here is for the same .cls file I am using, but now it is with redefinitions you suggested. http://pastebin.com/V1r87cP8

Comment: @Mara: I've updated `\l@chapter`. Let me know if this fixes your current setup (or not).

Comment: UPDATE:To Werner: I have examined the modification on cls file that you provided and it is now working nicely. Accordingly, I have updated the preamble. Thank you.

Comment: Update: To Werner. Sorry, I have just realized that was mistaken. Unfortunately, the modification did not work because of two problems. 1. Problem had accord with bold-font of the chapter numbers. Previously, I had defined bold-font numbers for chapters with the command \bfseries, and I had disabled the command \advance, and it was working, I mean only the number of the chapters were bold, but with the new modification,

Comment: the numbers are not bold and when I wanted to fix that, I got the numbers bold all together with the first page number and for the prefaces, references, appendices and the closure pages. 2. Based on the new boolean, the fist chapter still got its page number in the ToC, while the others working nicely. For time being, I would rather stick the first post you provide me, until I find a solution for these problems to make the cls file work easier with preamble tex file.

Comment: @Mara: 1. **Bold** chapter page numbers, but not **bold** chapter titles. Adding back the **bold** chapter numbers is easy if you want it for *all* the chapters. Just add `\bfseries` before `\thechappagenum` *or* before `#1` in the definition of `\thechappagenum`. Consider my two examples: the first has **bold** chapters while the other doesn't. Are you including additional packages that do that? 2. I introduced the boolean so you can switch between having chapter page numbers in the ToC or not. Do you want to remove the chapter page numbers *completely* or *selectively*? Be specific.

Comment: Before my last post, I tried this suggestion, it didn't work because adding \bfseries before \thechappagenum or before #1 in the definition of \thechappagenum will turn all the titles (chapters, sections, prefaces, ..., everything) into bold, which is not what I want. What already exist in cls file,  in ToC, were: 1. The sections, subsections are not bold, 2. All the chapter page numbers are not bold. 3. The titles of the prefaces, chapters, references, Appendices, closures are all bold, 4. The numbers corresponding to these titles are bold. Points 2 and 4 were working before,

Comment: and they were still working with your very first suggestions. I have cracked my packages, no any unusual package except \usepackage[font=bf]{caption}, but this only working for the captions of the tables and figures inside the body of the thesis, and as far as I know, it does not affect the ToC.
As for the request for me to be specific, only the page numbers of the titles of the chapters, I want them to disappear. Not the page numbers of the (prefaces, sections, subsections, references, appendices, closures.) Anyway, I have solved this problem now. When I tested it earlier,

Comment: I found that I put \gobbletocpage before the first chapter, so the result was keeping the page of the 1st chapter and the page numbers of the consecutive chapters have gone. Now, I put the \gobbletocpage before \include{abstract}, which is before my 1st chapter so that the page number of the 1st, and the consecutive chapters have gone. And I already put \restoretopage before the references because I wanted to appear. So, so far, with the modification you made, the chapter page numbers have gone.